# php form - onsubmit reset form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, onsubmit

I have created a form and everything is working fine so far. The only thing I have left is to reset the fields when the form is submitted. This seems like an easy task but after looking around and trying some things nothing seems to do the trick :( What I have now was taken from another post but my submit event was different from theirs which is why I think its not working. Any help is much appreciated.

php part

/////////////////////////////////upload image

```
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
define ("MAX_SIZE","500"); 

 //This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file   is an image by checking the extension.
function getExtension($str) {
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; }
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
}

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error     found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
$errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
//if it is not empty
if ($image) 
{
//get the original name of the file from the clients machine
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
//get the extension of the file in a lower case format
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") &&      ($extension != "gif")) 
    {
    //print error message
        echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
//get the size of the image in bytes
//$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
//in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
$size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}

$newname="storeImages/".$filename;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$errors) 
{
echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully!</h1>";
}

//direct to same page but refresh
//header('Location: storeListForm.php');

?>
```

The form

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onFormSubmit ()
{
    document.storeList.reset();
    return true; // allow form submission to continue
}
</script>

<div id="signUp"> 

<?php 
//if the validation falls back to php, then print the validation error
if (isset($error_message)) echo $error_message;
?>

<form method="post" action="" id="storeList" name="storeList" enctype="multipart/form-  data">  
<table>
<tr>
  <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> <label for="storeLocation">Location</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="storeLocation" id="storeLocation" value="<?php if   (isset($_POST['storeLocation'])) echo $_POST['storeLocation'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label for="featured_items">Featured Items</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="featured_items" id="featured_items" value="<?php if  (isset($_POST['featured_items'])) echo $_POST['featured_items'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label for="keywords">Keywords</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="<?php if     (isset($_POST['featured_items'])) echo $_POST['keywords'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label for="fileImage">Image</lable></td>
   <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>

</tr>
   <td>Description</td>
   <td> <textarea for="description"></textarea type="text area" name="description"  id="description" value="><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo  $_POST['description'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Store"  onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: the user enters input and then clicks submit. Everything submits ok but the fields still contain the input. I want them to be empty once the user submits so they can enter more data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this?

`onClick="this.form.reset()"`

(Yours is only `this.reset()`).

Comment: no go with that. It resets the form before it submits that data. Anyway around that?

Comment: wrap it in a `setTimeout()` You'll need to save a global reference to the form as `this` will be window.